# How to hide missing video link in html

Tags: html

Working on an html file that will only be used on my computer, nothing to be put up on the web.  I found html is much faster for what I'm trying to do than either VB or Python.  It searches a webpage for video files that are up on the webpage, some are there, some not.  The trouble is I don't want it to display a clickable link unless the video is on the webpage.  Is there anyway to do this?

Example of what I've tried:

embed src="http://www.a.com/videos/1234567.mp4">1234567

a href="http://www.a.com/videos/1234567.mp4">1234567

Naturally a href and embed will give you the 'link', including when no file is there.  I would much rather have it only show a clickable link when a file is present that I can download.  Is it possible with html only.  Is there anyway to work around the situation to accomplish what I'm trying using only html.

I could live with embed if I could right click on it and save the video that way but without a plugin I can't...not actually sure if I could if I was including a plugin in the code or not.  Then again, under the circumstance that would be a tricky situation when transferring the file to be used from a my laptop to a tablet which is the intended direction I'm leaning if I can get all my programs to run without the need for VB or quite frankly Python...most everything is internet based programs so if I can get things rewritten using html than I may actually be able to pull this crazy idea off.

Comment: _"It searches a webpage for video files that are up on the webpage"_ How? Where's your code?

Comment: I'm looking for a single file that I can run from Linux, err Windows 'Explorer'.  I can click on it and it will search the website and when it finds a file it will provide a clickable link otherwise it won't show anything.  I have this setup with VB, so it downloads the file as well but it's slower than molasses compared to the speed of html and to transfer it over to a tablet makes things more difficult than just using html.  Can I run php code on my own computer straight from Explorer or do I need the web 'structure' to run it.  HTML I can click and run.  Need a little more knowledge here:)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible with HTML alone, because HTML is a client-side language and cannot access the server's files.

To do this (check if a file exists on the server and disable the link), you must use a server-side language like PHP.

You can do this like this:

```
<?php

    $file_array = // list of filenames;

    echo "<script>";

    foreach($file_array as $path_to_file) {
        if(!file_exists($path_to_file)) {
            echo "document.querySelector('a[name=$path_to_file]').removeAttribute('href');";
        }
    }

    echo "</script>;

?>
```

This (is untested but) should have the PHP output JS that will remove all the `href` attributes from the links (thus disabling them) if the file doesn't exist (`!file_exists()`). But to do this you need to store all your filenames in the `$file_array` PHP variable.

Comment: +1; depending on the the CORS policy of `a.com` (in your example) you could also potentially do this with javascript and ajax requests